# Style element and ::before on hover

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-class

I'm trying to use CSS to make the text "Permits Required" and the ::before pseudo-class turn red - the ::before contains an icon.

```css
.knHeader__menu-list-item:hover::before {
  color: #aa0003 !important;
}

.knHeader__menu-list-item:hover {
  color: #aa0003 !important;
}
```

```html
<li class="knHeader__menu-list-item">
  ::before
  <a href="#permits-required" class="knHeader__menu-link knHeader__menu-link--text">
    <!---->

    Permits Required

    <!---->
  </a>
</li>
```

This makes only the icon turn red not the "Permits Required". I need both to turn red, at the same time when *either* of them are hovered over.

Comment: You might want to overwrite the deault `a` color as well (`.knHeader__menu-list-item > * { color: inherit; }`, which could create that issue.

Comment: is there a reason for not showing the css of `.knHeader__menu-list-item::before {` (and why did you use a complicate class names with 24 chararcters or more to illustrate your question ?)

Comment: Your HTML is a bit strange. What is the ::before in there? Perhaps you could create a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and there is no before pseudo element styling beyond the color change. What does it contain? And to get the a element to change color set CSS for that on the parent being hovered too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `color: inherit;`

sample code

```css
.class-li {
  color: green;
  }
.class-li a {
  color: inherit;
  }
.class-li::before {
  content : ':li-before: '
  }
.class-li:hover {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="class-li">
    <a href="#" class="class-a1 class-a2"> 
      Permits Required
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That doesn't even match the given scenario from the question here.

Comment: @CBroe that the way I understand the PO Question. Could you explain me the difference ?

Comment: They are not reacting to hover on the link itself, but the parent list item. And that likely introduces some specificity issue, which your reduced example of course won't have to begin with. If you remove the class from your link here, and then wrap it into `<div class="classXY"></div>` instead, you should likely already see the problem, due to the default link color applied via your browser stylesheet.

Comment: @CBroe changed my answer. is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over `.knHeader__menu-list-item` you are changing the ::before and the item itself. However its child `a` is still given the browsers default link styling. We can tell the `a` to inherit the colour from its parent:

```css
.knHeader__menu-list-item:hover a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Here's your demo snippet updated to do just that:

```css
.knHeader__menu-list-item::before {
  content: "(before)";
}

.knHeader__menu-list-item:hover {
  color: #aa0003;
}

.knHeader__menu-list-item:hover a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<li class="knHeader__menu-list-item">
  <a href="#permits-required" class="knHeader__menu-link knHeader__menu-link--text">
    Permits Required
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.knHeader__menu-list-item:hover::before,
.knHeader__menu-list-item:hover a {
  color: #aa0003 !important;
}

.knHeader__menu-list-item::before {
  content: 'Icon';
  }
```

```html
<li class="knHeader__menu-list-item">
  <a href="#permits-required" class="knHeader__menu-link knHeader__menu-link--text">
  <!---->
  Permits Required
  <!---->
  </a>
</li>
```

Try the above.